# Getting the values of li tag in the code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an aspx view in which i have this snippet:

```html
 <div class="widgetcontent bordered">
     <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span3 profile-left">
            <ul class="taglist" id="metiers" runat="server">
           <li style="line-height: 20px"><a  style="width:250px">this is<span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
             </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I need to get all the **li** tag values inside the `metiers` element in the code behind
So :

- How can i do that?
- What is the best practise?

Comment: You have 2 options i think, put `runnat=server` and id to `li` and ge the vales at codebehind (easy way) or by Jquery Ajax.

Comment: Can u explain the second way please, because the first didn't match with my case because i add dynamically li tag by a script jquery and i don't need to refredh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough context to give you an exact solution but I think what you're looking for would look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ListVals" id="listVals" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetListVals(){
         var listVals = $('#metiers').children().html();

        $('#listVals').val(encodeURIComponent(listVals));
    }
</script>
```

Call SetListvals() before the page is posted and then check the value of the listVals control.  You'll need to unencode it's value.